# HttpClient(windows universal app) upload image into php script fail

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have php script with this code

```
$tmp_image = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$data = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($tmp_image));
$sql = "update userinfo set Picture = '$data' where ID = '$ID'";
$returnArray['Data'] = $sql.$ID;
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

and I have .Net code

```
MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
HttpContent data = new ByteArrayContent(x.PixelBuffer.ToArray());//x=WriteableBitmap with image
data.Add(content, '"'+ "file"+'"', '"'+"userphoto.jpg"+'"');
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var post = await client.PostAsync(ServerPath, data);
var result = await post.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

and after code run complete I see that result have this value
{"Data":null}
and table didn't update
as I understand sql query didn't run because I send wrong image byte array. But can't understand what wrong I send.

Comment: Did you try not adding the extra quotes?